# Using socat to access deluge daemon in a different namespace

Tags: port-forwarding, namespace, socat, network-namespaces, deluge

I'm using [namespaced-openvpn](https://github.com/slingamn/namespaced-openvpn) to ensure that my torrent traffic in deluge is always behind a VPN.
A modified script from [this blog post](https://schnouki.net/post/2014/openvpn-for-a-single-application-on-linux/) helped to connect the VPN namespace to the real network:

```
ip link add vpn0 type veth peer name vpn1
ip link set vpn0 up
ip link set vpn1 netns <NS-NAME> up
ip addr add 10.200.200.1/24 dev vpn0
ip netns exec <NS-NAME> ip addr add 10.200.200.2/24 dev vpn1
ip netns exec <NS-NAME> ip route add default via 10.200.200.1 dev vpn1

iptables -A INPUT \! -i vpn0 -s 10.200.200.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.200.0/24 -o en+ -j MASQUERADE
sysctl -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Deluge can then be started in the namespace:

`sudo ip netns exec <NS-NAME> sudo -u $USER deluged`

I initially used [this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258967) to run both the deluge daemon and deluge-web in the same namespace and simply forward requests to the web ui port with socat:

`socat tcp-listen:8112,reuseaddr,fork tcp-connect:10.200.200.2:8112`

This works fine for using deluge normally, but for scripting reason I need access to the daemon itself, so I moved deluge-web out of the namespace and tried the following command for the daemon port:

`socat tcp-listen:58846,reuseaddr,fork tcp-connect:10.200.200.2:58846`

But when trying to reach the daemon through the web UI socat produces the following error:

```
2019/04/07 18:40:47 socat[13957] E connect(5, AF=2 10.200.200.2:58846, 16): Connection refused
```

Using [this python library](https://pypi.org/project/deluge-client/) to connect to the daemon like so:

```py
from deluge_client import DelugeRPCClient
client = DelugeRPCClient('127.0.0.1', 58846, 'user', 'pw')
client.connect()
```

throws the error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1109, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1100, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:847)
```